# Recode column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large dataset and need to recode a few numeric variables to other numeric values. A portion of my dataset looks like this:

```
condition.10 financial.condition behavior.condition outcome Gender Race
1            6                   1                  3       0   Male    5
2            7                   0                  4       0 Female    5
3            5                   0                  3       1 Female    5
4            2                   1                  1       1   Male  2,5
5           10                   1                  5       0 Female    5
6            6                   1                  3       1   Male    5
```

I want to recode race into 3 "bins" of 1, 2, 3- "white", "Black", and "Other" respectively. I have managed to achieve that with this code:

```
mydata$Race <- NA
mydata$Race <- mydata$Q73
mydata$Race[mydata$Race==1|mydata$Race==2|mydata$Race==4|mydata$Race==6]<-6
mydata$Race[mydata$Race==3]<-2
mydata$Race[mydata$Race==5]<-1
mydata$Race[mydata$Race==6]<-3
```

I also tried this:

```
case_when(mydata$Race %in% c(1,2,4,6) ~3,
mydata$Race %in% 3 ~ 2,
mydata$Race %in% 5 ~1,
TRUE ~ as.numeric(mydata$Race))
```

The first bit gives me what I need, but it doesn't account for people checking two races such as that in the 4th row.

Any advice would be appreciated. I already ready recode from car package and dplyr.

Maybe it just me being so new, but it hurts not being able to do the basics.

```
unique(mydata$Race)
# [1] 5 2,5 2 3 6 3,5 1,5 1,2,4,5 1 1,2,5 4,6 3,6 2,3 1,3 4
# [16] 2,4,5,6 1,3,5 4,5
# Levels: 1 1,2,4,5 1,2,5 1,3 1,3,5 1,5 2 2,3 2,4,5,6 2,5 3 3,5 3,6 4 4,5 4,6 5 6
```

**Note:** I am *very* new to R and am looking for some guidance.

Comment: How would you code 4th row `2, 5` as 1 or 3?

Comment: To be decided at a later date. Ideally, I would like 2 to change to 3 and the 5 to change to 1. If I were pressed, I would say 1.

Comment: Could you check the unique values in Race column, shouw us the output of `unique(mydata$Race)` ?

Comment: `unique(mydata$Race)
     [1] 5       2,5     2       3       6       3,5     1,5     1,2,4,5 1       1,2,5   4,6     3,6     
    2,3     1,3     4      
    [16] 2,4,5,6 1,3,5   4,5    
    Levels: 1 1,2,4,5 1,2,5 1,3 1,3,5 1,5 2 2,3 2,4,5,6 2,5 3 3,5 3,6 4 4,5 4,6 5 6`


I'm not sure how to make this a more readable

Comment: I added the output of unique to your post, you can always add more details to your post by clicking on "edit".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a lookup named vector then loop through values:

```
# example data
df1 <- data.frame(Race = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "5,2", "6"))

# map, named vector
lookup <- setNames(c(3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3), 1:6)
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 
# 3 3 2 3 1 3 

df1$RaceClean <- sapply(as.character(df1$Race), function(i){
  paste(lookup[ unlist(strsplit(i, ",")) ], collapse = ",")
  })

df1
#   Race RaceClean
# 1    1         3
# 2    2         3
# 3    3         2
# 4    4         3
# 5    5         1
# 6  5,2       1,3
# 7    6         3
```

Comment: Would the lookup table need to be comprised of each of the 16 unique values?

Answer (score 0):

We can create a lookup table with the Race codes you're looking for.  Anything not in that table, we can call "Other".

```
library(tidyverse)

#create a lookup table
RaceTable <- data.frame(Race = c(3, 5),
                        RaceName = c("White", "Black"),
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

mydata %>% 
  #bring in RaceName from the lookup table
  left_join(RaceTable, by = c("Race" = "Race")) %>% 
  #if there is no RaceName, call it "Other"
  mutate(RaceName = replace(RaceName, is.na(RaceName), "Other"))
```

Comment: I get a peculiar error which presumably changes a lot.

`"Error in left_join_impl(x, y, by_x, by_y, aux_x, aux_y, na_matches) : 
  Can't join on 'Race' x 'Race' because of incompatible types (factor / numeric)"`

Comment: Sounds like Race is a factor in mydata.  You could convert it to numeric `mydata$Race <- as.numeric(mydata$Race)` which would leave your multi-racial entries as NA, but that would just mean they end up classified as "Other" in the end